# Mains failure detection circuit

Tags: ac, circuit-design

I am trying to find out a mains power OFF detection circuit. Basically, when the wall switch is OFF and the mains power is ON, it should detect that. And when both wall switch and mains are OFF it should detect and give an alarm. Below is the logic for this.

[image]

Can somebody suggest some idea to solve this?

Comment: the state of the switch is irrelevant ... why are you including it?

Comment: this looks like a school assignment for beginner digital logic. .... is it homework?

Comment: You want a device that plugs into the wall and ignores the switch in the wall? You might not have much luck there.

Comment: Usually, there is a ground to a neutral voltage of less than 2V is present even if the wall switch is OFF  and when the mains are ON. Is this a possibility to detect mains by ignoring mains.( truth table is for better understanding .I know that this is not a digital logic.)

Comment: you will have "better understanding" if you remove all references to the switch

Comment: we will have "better understanding" if you explain fully what you are doing

Comment: My idea is to design a standalone emergency bulb which can turn ON only when the mains are OFF.

Comment: Where is your standalone emergency bulb going to be powered from?

Comment: It would be powered from 230V AC  like any normal bulb.

Comment: If the mains are off, there is no power available for your emergency bulb. It won't be able to turn 'On'. Or am I confused?

Comment: Emergency bulb will be having a lithium ion battery

Comment: You said "It would be powered from 230V AC like any normal bulb." AND you said "Emergency bulb will be having a lithium ion battery" SO which is it?

Answer (score 1):

Your truth table shows no dependency on the switch position.

An AC-coil relay rated for mains voltage and connected across the mains will perform this function- use the normally closed contact on a form-C relay.

Comment: "Your truth table shows no dependency on the switch position." - pretty sure that is intentional to show that the output must not be affected by it. But s/he will have a hard time detecting mains power from a wall outlet when the wall outlet is switched off.

Comment: @immibis A closed contact is "detection"- presumably there is a battery or whatever to run the alarm like the beeper on a UPS.

Answer (score 1):

Using your comment about the Emergency Bulb being power from a Lithium Ion battery, you could do something similar to this circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpLmmY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is probably not a perfect solution for a few reasons:

1. You would be splicing into Mains circuit which is dangerous.
2. You now have Mains voltage running to wherever you locate the relay, if for instance you put the relay on your desk, this too would be a dangerous situation.
3. Any laws in your area that regulate this type of thing.
4. The relay is constantly using a little bit of power.
5. Your bulb only lasts as long as the battery lasts.
6. There is no method of recharging the battery or monitoring it's level.
7. I could go on...

Comment: I have seen similar bulb that matches my idea.. Please see the link https://youtu.be/4CyfE6b_U0c